# Integration testing with Testcontainers/Localstack and Spring Boot: Set directory for temporary files

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, testcontainers, localstack

I am using Testcontainers' (Localstack Module)[https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/localstack/] for advanced integration testing with Spring Boot, replacing the AmazonS3 client with the one from Localstack. I have set up my integration test roughly as follows (only relevant parts):

```kotlin
// FurnitureDetailsControllerIT.kt

@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@DirtiesContext
class FurnitureDetailsControllerIT {

  @Autowired
  private val amazonS3: AmazonS3? = null

  
  companion object {
    @Container
    var localStack: LocalStackContainer =
      LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:latest")).withServices(LocalStackContainer.Service.S3)

    @JvmStatic
    @DynamicPropertySource
    fun properties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
      registry.add("cloud.aws.s3.endpoint") { localStack.getEndpointOverride(LocalStackContainer.Service.S3) }
      registry.add("cloud.aws.credentials.access-key") { localStack.accessKey }
      registry.add("cloud.aws.credentials.secret-key") { localStack.secretKey }
    }
  }
(...)
}
```

Everything runs fine when running the integration test locally (from my IDE or command line using Maven), meaning I can see the localstack container spinning up in the logs:

```
13:54:16.360 [main] INFO  [remote-docker.artifactory.mycompany.com/localstack/localstack:0.13.0] - Container remote-docker.artifactory.mycompany.com/localstack/localstack:0.13.0 started in PT4.6099665S
```

However, when running on Jenkins, the build fails because of an error message.

```
2022-09-28 14:27:19.971  INFO 1185 --- [           main] ?.a.s.com/localstack/localstack:latest]  : Container remote-docker.artifactory.mycompany.com/localstack/localstack:latest is starting: ec383bda85f2636c3bef3f6b3938ac169636e4542244e3067b5184b6b03a6e35

2022-09-28 14:28:20.612 ERROR 1185 --- [           main] ?.a.s.com/localstack/localstack:latest]  : Could not start container

org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for log output matching '.*Ready\.
```

I guess it has to do with the temporary directory needed by Localstack. When running on my Windows machine I have to manually click on "Share It" before the test resumes:

[image: Docker Desktop notification for file sharing (Windows)]

I suppose since the test is failing on Jenkins (because I cannot click on "Share It" there) starting the container will eventually time out and the test will fail.

I read that you can configure the directory using the `TMPDIR` environment variable as described in https://docs.localstack.cloud/localstack/configuration/. But using that variable is deprecated. What is the best way to set the temp directory to Jenkins working directory without having to explicitly conset to sharing that directory?

Note: I am already using Testcontainers' [MongoBD module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mongodb/) successfully, which starts a dockerized MongoDB instance. That works flawlessly, so I am not sure if it's an issue with Testcontainers or Localstack.

Comment: I see you created it as an issue in the repository as well. I'll continue interacting there :)

Comment: That's right, out of despair I cross-posted this as an issue to the repository :): https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/5869

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with the company proxy after all. For some reason, LocalStack needs to download dependencies at runtime:

From https://docs.localstack.cloud/localstack/configuration/:

> OUTBOUND_HTTP_PROXY: HTTP Proxy used for downloads of runtime dependencies and connections outside LocalStack itself

Since our Jenkins is behind a corporate proxy, I had to set the following environment variables: `SKIP_SSL_CERT_DOWNLOAD`, `OUTBOUND_HTTP_PROXY`, `OUTBOUND_HTTPS_PROXY`. On top of that I had to hardcode the version to `1.1.0` instead of using the `latest` tag.

So my code now looks like this:

```kotlin
    LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:1.1.0"))
      .withServices(LocalStackContainer.Service.S3)
      .withEnv("SKIP_SSL_CERT_DOWNLOAD", "true")
      .withEnv("OUTBOUND_HTTP_PROXY", "http://{proxy}:{port}")
      .withEnv("OUTBOUND_HTTPS_PROXY", "http://{proxy}:{port}")
      .apply { start() }
```

Comment: I also faced same issue and now after adding proxy I am getting 403 forbidden with S3. I think this is coming because of proxy. Do you know how to fix this?